# How to access points in a grid formed by dividing 2d space in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, grid, logistic-regression

I have a data-set consisting of 2 features which are non separable. I am dividing my space into nxn grid and then planning to apply logistic regression individually to those grids to find nxn parameters for testing data. I am not to figure out how to access the points within a particular grid in Matlab. I have successfully divided the space into n*n grid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "magic" way to access points in the grid, but just use a basic maths here. If you create a uniformly spaced grid, lets say `n` in size, spanning the total space of [0,1] x [0,1] (for simplicity) then you can get index of the cell given new point (x,y) by computing [floor(x * n), floor(y * n)]. For example n=10, (x,y) = (0.41, 0.12) => [floor(x * n), floor(y * n)] = [floor(0.41 * 10), floor(0.12 * 10)] = [4, 1].

However, the whole idea of splitting 2d space to grid and fit linear models in each grid is rather bad. Just fit a nonlinear model, even knn should work just fine in 2d. Your approach has so many dissadvantages - you get very small fraction of points to fit each model, each of them will not be able to perform hyperaprameters optimization, some cells will be empty and you will need a heuristic to deal with them (and your data seems so easy to work with that any guessing/heuristic looks like a horrible idea), you will get huge number of models to work with, you introduce another "magical" hyperaparameter of n, your decision boundary will be highly non-contiuous and non smooth.... really - this is a very simple problem, you do not need to invent anything - there are dozens of simple models which will work just fine.

Comment: I have to implement the following thing:
Train logistic regression model on discretized representation of 2-
dimensional samples. Please try equally dividing the space into {2^2,4^2,8^2,16^2} grids, and use cross-validation to choose the optimal discretization resolution. Please report the training, heldout and testing accuracies for these 4 models. You may assume every raw feature of all samples are within [2; 2].

Comment: You seem to missunderstand the question. It asks to discretize data and train a single LR on top of it, not LR per hypercube.

Comment: So do I need to create bins and then proceed?

Comment: Yes, this is what the cited text asks for.

Comment: So how should I proceed with logistic regression in such a case?

Comment: there is nothing special about it - just bin your features, which gives you new representation of your data, and fit regular logistic regression on this one-hot encodings.

Comment: " One solution in practice is to discretize features and represent them as multiple Boolean features, that's, one raw feature is described with one multi-dimensional indicator vector. Take the datasets  for example: we used blue and red colors to represent two
classes, and obviously none of they are linearly separable. However, if we discretize the region of [-2, 2] x [-2, 2] into 16 equal size rectangle grids, we can represent each sample with a 16-dimensional indicator vector, and intuitively we can expect a better classication accuracy. "
 
With 4 grids, # features=8 for each sample?

Comment: with K grids (cells) you get K features, that's all.

Comment: So if a point is in grid one say, then how to represent its two features represented by x and y coordinate?
Thanks.